# Discord bot won't respond to slash commands?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am new to making discord bots, and I have run into a severe issue. The bot won't even respond to slash commands, which is essential to discord bots. Here's my current code:

```
const { GatewayIntentBits, messageLink, SlashCommandBuilder, Events } = require('discord.js');

const { Client, Partials } = require("discord.js")

console.log(GatewayIntentBits)
const auth = require('./auth.json')
const token = auth.token
const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    ],
    partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message, Partials.Reaction, Partials.User, Partials.GuildMember]
})
bot.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    if (interaction.commandName === 'pinger') {
        await interaction.reply({content: "Ponger..", ephemeral: true})
    }
})

bot.login(token)
```

I've tried to search for the problem, nothing seems to be helpful.
I have all the intents set up and everything...

Comment: Have you deployed your slash commands?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can visit the guide here: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#command-registration